# Array difference and on change update value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays from which i generate dynamic input fields into 2 different `div` like below .

So once the input fields are created the user can alter the value inside an input field in `div` one or `div` two  .
If you notice `div` one and `div` two can have the same input field in this case `firstname` with same value of "john".

How can i do a check to see if the value of firstname has changed in `div` one or `div` two ?
If the value of firstname has changed  in `div` one or `div` two which ever is current  than I take its value to submission ,I may have more than one similar fieldset and i need to do this on all similar field sets

So I'll submit

```
var finaldata= {firstname:"abraham", lastname:"Doe" ,age:46, address:"newyork" ,mobile:"04126562356"} 
var arrayone = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
var arraytwo = {firstName:"John", address:"newyork",mobile:"04126562356"};
```

Then I will loop through `arrayone` and output its values into a `div`

```
<div id="arrayone_panel">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">
   <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe">
   <input type="text" name="age"  value="46">
</div>
```

And for  `arraytwo` I will loop through and output its values into another `div`

```
<div id="arraytwo_panel">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">  
   <input type="text" name="address" value="newyork">
   <input type="text" name="mobile" value="04126562356">
</div>
```

Comment: These are **objects** and not arrays, and what you are trying to do, doesn't make much sense but I think you are trying to reproduce angular `data-binding`.

Comment: try having a id for each object and use data attribute to map the id with the object so whenever a input field changes search using the id and change the respective object.

Comment: What if firstname changes in both?

Comment: Thanks  xotic  in this case user will only change the value of one.
Thanks manish for the idea .

Comment: Why not only display `firstname` for `arrayone`? Is it necessary to display it twice?

Comment: Xotic750  actually I have two panels and each panel is linked to different data sources and different databases   so when i pull the data objects from databaseone i put it into arrayone  and so when i pull data objects from database two i put it into arraytwo .. so for the most part the values  of each array are different but from time to time some same field sets occur  so  if the fields are same and no change has occurred than i resubmit the values to a 3rd db if a user  updates the firstname in either panel one or panel two than  i submit the the updated value to my 3rd database  ......

Comment: Ok, so display both but disable one, so that only changes can be made in the enabled one. Your 3rd DB is a merge of both datasets, right?

Answer (score 1):

you can attach event listeners to the both inputs separately and then take value for submission from respective event handlers, something like this:

```
$("#arrayone_panel").on('input', "[name='firstname']",function({
    //code..

}))


$("#arraytwo_panel").on('input', "[name='firstname']",function({
    //code..

}))
```

Comment: nice but I'll need to attach event listeners for all inputs to monitor if input has changed and if so take those values.

I think manish answer is the closes to what i am trying to do but i have no clue about mapping.

try having a id for each object and use data attribute to map the id with the object so whenever a input field changes search using the id and change the respective object.